# ng-click not updating UI automatically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having trouble displaying a `<td>` in my `ng-repeat` produced table.

The last `<td>` in the table should be displayed based on a condition, if `vm.editDeleteButtonsVisibile` (Using the `Controller-As` syntax) is true. By default this value is false but when I change it to true, the UI doesn't reflect the change.

This is how my `<tbody>` looks:

```
<tbody ng-controller="EditProductController as vm"> <!-- This ng-controller is somewhere else -->
    <tr ng-repeat="product in vm.products">
        <td>{{ product.productName}}</td>
        <td>{{ product.productCode }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.releaseDate | date }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.price | currency }}</td>
        <td width="15%" ng-if="vm.editDeleteButtonsVisible"> <!-- Error Here -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.editItem(product.productCode)">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="vm.deleteItem(product.productCode)">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the controller where I'm updating the value `vm.editDeleteButtonsVisible`:

```
var EditProductController = function() {
    vm.editDeleteButtonsVisible = false; // Default value

    vm.showEditDeleteButtons = function() {
        vm.editDeleteButtonsVisible = true;
        console.log(vm.editDeleteButtonsVisible); // Prints true, so value was updated
    }
}
```

This is how `vm.showEditDeleteButtons()` is being called, from another view:

```
<div id="editProductBtn" ng-controller="EditProductController as pvm">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="pvm.showEditDeleteButtons()">Edit Products</button>
</div>
```

Could the problem be that I'm already declaring `ng-controller="EditProductController"`? I declare it once in it's main view and another time in a separate view.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with the code you've shared so far. Can you try to reproduce the problem in a Plunker?

Comment: have your tried using 'ng-show' instead of 'ng-if' ?

Comment: @Newboy I've tried `ng-show`, `ng-if`, even `ng-switch`

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen Exactly what i'm sayin! Nothing looks wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are defining the controller twice. Angular controllers are not singletons. So you are creating two instances of it. You are updating a variable in one of them and looking for it in the other. This won't work.

```
<div id="editProductBtn" ng-controller="EditProductController as pvm">
```

and

```
<tbody ng-controller="EditProductController as vm">
```

Creates two instances.
What you need to do is either use one controller or create a service (which IS a singleton) and hold the variable in the service.

Comment: As suspected! I moved the logic into one controller, and removed all the references to `ng-controller` in the `HTML`. I already defined controllers in my `$route`. Works as expected! Although I did have to move the buttons from the master view into a view to be injected using `<ng-view>`.